# Removing print slows down the while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, while-loop, python-multithreading

I want my python file to wait for all threads to close.
I am using next code:

```
threadslist=int(threading.active_count())
while threadslist>1:
  threadslist=int(threading.active_count())

print(Fore.BLUE+"Scan of ports Ended in:"+Style.RESET_ALL, Fore.GREEN+str(round(time.time()-start_time))+Style.RESET_ALL, "s")
```

With that code i get this:
`Scan of ports finished in 128 s`
But when I put `print(threadslist)` in while loop it speeds up.
Second code:

```
threadslist=int(threading.active_count())
while threadslist>1:
  threadslist=int(threading.active_count())
    print(threadslist)
print(Fore.BLUE+"Scan of ports Ended in:"+Style.RESET_ALL, Fore.GREEN+str(round(time.time()-start_time))+Style.RESET_ALL, "s")
```

Now i get:
`Scan of ports Ended in 26 s`
Why does it take longer to finish loop without print, but not with it?
When i am not checking for threads to end, i have time of 20 s, and than 6 s for python to wait, so second time is normal.

Comment: Why not just ```join()``` all the threads in a loop? Continuous polling like this is inefficient.

Comment: Instead of `print(...)`, you could try `time.sleep(0.1)`. This might improve the runtime even more. Ultimately as has been pointed out `.join()` is the way to go.

Comment: .join will take long, cause i have 65k threads genetated. I can be wrong, but that what u think will happen

Comment: Well, you seem to have set up some sort of performance check already. Perhaps you could now first try `time.sleep(0.1)`, and then just a loop to `.join()` each thread in turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Busy-looping is not an efficient way to wait for threads to end.  When you do that, you are using up billions of CPU cycles simply calling a function and checking its result over and over again.

Worse, in Python you are implicitly holding the GIL to do that, which means your other threads cannot run for much of the time.  That is what is slowing down their execution.  Adding the print statement in means that your main thread is at least doing I/O some of the time, which allows your other threads to acquire the GIL a bit more often and therefore complete more quickly.

The correct thing for your main thread to do is call join() on each of the spawned threads in sequence.  That will have the same effect but not waste CPU cycles, since join() will efficiently block/sleep until the thread has exited

Comment: The problem is, i generate 65k threads, and joining them will take time, won't it?

Comment: Don’t generate 65k threads… that’s too many.  If you think you need that many, you should be using a thread pool instead.